# SSAS first cube with facttable, is kinda hard

Tags: ssas

Link to DCD: http://i48.tinypic.com/29de538.png

I have this DCD to work on, with SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008.

I have made a facttable which is a view, because I need to have some measures..

Now how do I connect my facttable to the other tables? Dont know if the should be linked to selftest, instrument or network.

It would be great to hear the correct linking, and how to do it!

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi again.

Could it be that the facttable is actually the Selftest table?
Maybe I should make the four facts, four Named Queries in selftest table?

All anwsers are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have Instrument (first dimension), execution date (second dimension) and a resulting status (third dimension) for each Self Test.  You may generate hierarchies of Instrument Type, Group and Network to group together Instruments within ssas.

The resulting counts (NumOk, NumWarning, NumError) may be your measures.  Typically, you would group these together depending on the grain of your fact (i.e. daily) to a single fact table.  There is no need to create separate facts per measures, you would only create separate fact tables if the measures relate to a different set of dimensions

Try to set your source up as follows (add additional attributes as required) and follow the model through to the DSV.  Suggest that you ignore hierarchies until you get the basics working within SSAS.

[image: Self test example]

Comment: First off, thank you for writing!

But I dont fully grasp the linking between the entities..

I have created the three dimentions; Instrument, ExecutionDate, ResultingStatus

http://i45.tinypic.com/14trbpl.png

Is it somewhat what you meant!? :)

btw. I think you got what I am trying to do.. :)

Comment: I was wondering if I should use a named query for making the facttable?

Comment: Now you need to add the id's of your dimensions to each fact.  In your source system, either edit your fact to have the dimension id's stamped against each row or work it out on the fly within the fact select statement.  Either way, your fact needs to enter SSAS with a statement like  "SELECT DimId1, DimId2, DimId3, Measure1, Measure2, Measure3 and so on..."  With a fact table (preferably via a view) formed as above, you will be able to link the dimensions to fact within the SSAS Data Source View.  btw, forget about hierarchies etc until you get the basic fact / dimension processing

Comment: Okay im trying to do what you suggedsted. But did I make the first things right? Because in the dimention Instrument, Im not sure if I should have all the tables included, also Selftests didn't come up as a sugguestion, because its relation is the other way. Is that right?
And the ResultingStatus, I put in ssasSelfTest there.. Does it look right?

Im trying to cope with the changes right now.

I though the fundamental video training by pluralsight would do wonders, but I think its a school example, not eligible for my example, just gives me a headache..

Comment: Okay now I linked the facts with the dimentions.. or not.. I did it in my DSV, hope thats what is meant?

heres a screenshot: http://i48.tinypic.com/2mhiqkj.png

But can't seem to fint the date dimention there..

Comment: If you dont really have time time to help me get the first version up and running, before I begin to really investegate the big subject, you can just right something like "you should read more before asking again" and I will give u a 'solved' - with that said, I really wanted to get the first version though, it seems like it pretty straigt forward, but with a lot of settings u need to understand.. I acually got my first cube made some days ago, and was able to play with it in excel, but some of the figures was wrong.

Comment: Michael, you should read more about data warehouses and ssas to help you understand the basics.  Maybe try http://www.kimballgroup.com/ to start with.  I have added a diagram to the answer which should help you on your way.  You need to structure your fact table differently before consuming it in the cube.

Comment: I just got the cube created with a time dimention today. I didn't need the facttable, I use the selfteststep and selftest table, thanks for trying to help! :)